# React Native Redux - Limiting component rerenders caused when redux state changes (for array children)

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

I am passing redux state into my component using the following

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  rdx_myColorPreference: state.profile.mySelf.preferences[4],
});
```

My goal is that the component ***only*** rerenders when the 5th child in the preferences array is changed (i.e. `preferences[4]`....which relates to color preferences).

Problem is that when ANY child in the preferences array changes (e.g. `preferences[0]`....which relates to food preferences), the component rerenders.

Comment: Put more code, what useEffect or componentDidUpdate are you using, how is the render() in your code, etc

Answer (score 1):

Each child should be a pure component (use React.memo) and when you pass a function from the parent then make sure you don't pass a newly created function each time the parent renders so you need to do `onChange={function}` and not `onChange={()=>newly created function}`.

Here is an example:

```js
const { Provider, useDispatch, useSelector } = ReactRedux;
const { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } = Redux;
const { memo, useCallback } = React;

const initialState = {
  items: [
    { id: 1, value: '' },
    { id: 2, value: '' },
    { id: 3, value: '' },
  ],
};
//action types
const CHANGE_ITEM = 'CHANGE_ITEM';
//action creators
const changeItem = (id, value) => ({
  type: CHANGE_ITEM,
  payload: { id, value },
});
const reducer = (state, { type, payload }) => {
  if (type === CHANGE_ITEM) {
    const { id, value } = payload;
    return {
      ...state,
      items: state.items.map((item) =>
        item.id !== id ? item : { ...item, value }
      ),
    };
  }
  return state;
};
//selectors
const selectItems = (state) => state.items;
//creating store with redux dev tools
const composeEnhancers =
  window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  initialState,
  composeEnhancers(
    applyMiddleware(
      () => (next) => (action) => next(action)
    )
  )
);
//use React.memo to create a pure component
const Item = memo(function Item({
  item: { id, value },
  onChange,
}) {
  console.log('render item wih id:', id);
  return (
    <ul>
      {id}
      <input
        type="text"
        value={value}
        onChange={(e) => onChange(id, e.target.value)}
      />
    </ul>
  );
});
const App = () => {
  const items = useSelector(selectItems);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  //create this onChange function on mount using React.useCallback
  const onChange = useCallback(
    (id, value) => dispatch(changeItem(id, value)),
    //dependencies is dispatch but that will never change so it is
    //  only created on mount
    [dispatch]
  );
  return (
    <ul>
      {items.map((item) => (
        <Item
          key={item.id}
          item={item}
          onChange={onChange}
        />
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/redux/4.0.5/redux.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-redux/7.2.0/react-redux.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```